# Need to encrypt and decrypt data using RSA XML key in nodejs

Tags: c#, node.js, xml, rsa, pem

I am trying to consume a web service created in C# through nodejs which returns a public RSA XML key to encrypt the parameters and send them back in request.

For example:

`<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>c62A/5klhhu5yiqlyE9gwbsnr5PwsCJNC2D3m67pvnqP9nbtQdqRTnf0/ijS2xlo50OpugvDR7qUUD6gY7ptFNogpRQIYpDAC0E+Y977r3vUuRx8XuI6SKjA4IyFXdhYS8wJaQPcqOCpwCKJ3Or5PwdZyl+/HqzmbHIAcrYbRDS=</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>`

But in nodejs, I am not able to find any module which can encrypt the data directly using RSA XML key.

Instead I have to convert the XML key to PEM using its Modulus and Exponent and encrypt the parameters but I think the web service is not able to decrypt it in that case.

Comment: Are there any docs for the web service to help you? What does an example XML key look like?

Comment: OK. What Node libraries handle RSA asymmetric encryption? I assume one can do a search on the NPM site.

Comment: Have you tried [Chilkat](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/nodejs.asp)